# How do I get outer divs to stack properly when there is absolute positioning inside the first one?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I am confused on how to get these divs to stack the way I want them to. I can't get the main content div (`.innerdiv2`) to stack below the first header div (`.innerdiv1`) that has/involves absolute positioning (so that the one image is on top of the other).

I also need to refrain from using fixed height on the image. This is the suggestion I have found most when searching for related posts and solutions. But I don't want that (fixed height) to lock in where the second div starts on the page. If the screen is sized down then I want the two header images to size down proportionally, which means they will decrease in height and the second div should start higher, which is why I don't want to use fixed height. Is this possible?

Here is the code I am working with:

```css
  .maindiv {
    position: relative;
  }

  .innerdiv1 {
    max-width: 975px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .imgbg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 102;
    max-width: 975px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .imglogo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 103;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 33%;
  }

  .innerdiv2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tbl1 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 975px;
    " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0;
  }

  .imgfooter {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 975px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="maindiv">
      <div class="innerdiv1">
        <img class="imgbg" src="http://www.pegaweb.com/tutorials/web-page-header/5.gif">
        <img class="imglogo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
      </div>
      <div class="innerdiv2">
        <table class="tbl1">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>
                1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ultrices justo justo, ac consequat arcu pellentesque id. Nulla hendrerit dui vitae neque venenatis consequat. Morbi justo eros, dictum et enim et, pellentesque fermentum augue. Aliquam
                non sapien eros. Sed auctor enim ac blandit rhoncus. Vivamus condimentum ex nulla, quis laoreet risus sodales quis. Vivamus interdum aliquam ultricies. Donec consectetur turpis et vehicula hendrerit. Fusce ac dui nec odio convallis malesuada
                id ultricies lectus.
              </p>
              <p>
                2. Nam mi enim, bibendum id porttitor quis, posuere ac arcu. Donec pulvinar enim nec gravida accumsan. Fusce enim risus, laoreet nec venenatis aliquam, feugiat a sapien. Aenean vulputate fermentum ex, at cursus diam cursus vel. Vivamus maximus velit mi,
                ut auctor libero hendrerit ut. Donec vel pharetra nulla. Aenean imperdiet elementum felis vel finibus. Aenean eu luctus velit, nec accumsan velit.
              </p>
              <p>
                3. Nullam pharetra orci nec lacinia bibendum. Ut tortor dolor, feugiat sed nulla ac, ultricies vehicula mi. Donec in arcu tincidunt, convallis lectus eu, ornare eros. Duis mollis ultrices lacus vulputate iaculis. Quisque urna lorem, consectetur in sollicitudin
                ut, volutpat et ex. Integer finibus malesuada ipsum, eget consequat nulla interdum et. Maecenas ullamcorper ante turpis, vitae mattis libero ultricies a. Duis bibendum sapien vitae molestie interdum.
              </p>
              <p>
                4. Vestibulum cursus ipsum augue, eget consequat dui ullamcorper sed. Phasellus a ligula eu tellus posuere tristique quis eu odio. Nullam id est in orci pharetra tempus sed dictum sem. Phasellus vehicula iaculis augue ac scelerisque. Sed pretium eros
                sed tortor condimentum viverra. Quisque euismod sed ante eu facilisis. Quisque rhoncus auctor arcu at aliquet. Pellentesque eleifend leo at nisl fringilla sagittis. Sed augue erat, faucibus a nulla at, porttitor volutpat dui.
              </p>
              <p>
                5. Maecenas semper erat euismod, ultricies augue et, aliquam ipsum. Sed commodo diam a posuere tristique. Vestibulum placerat risus orci, vitae finibus libero vulputate sed. Vestibulum ac nulla maximus, lobortis turpis interdum, tempor lectus. Fusce pretium
                scelerisque viverra. Vestibulum aliquam at ex eget sollicitudin. Proin in vehicula velit. Nam eget metus sed dui lobortis pulvinar sit amet sed tortor. Aliquam eu nunc a tortor ultricies euismod.
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img class="imgfooter" src="http://www.pegaweb.com/tutorials/web-page-header/5.gif">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b2tngLym/8/

Comment: The reason for your issue is you are using absolute positioning which removes that element from the normal flow. That is why the other elements are able to move into that space. The standard way to prevent that is to position its parent element 'relative' and do 'overflow:auto;' so it will expand to contain the absolutely positioned child element and keep the others in their place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2tngLym/7/)

```
      .imgbg { width: 100%; }
      .innerdiv1 {
        max-width: 975px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
      }


      .imglogo {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 103;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 33%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0
      }
```

Comment: I don't want to do this because as I said in the post, when the page is sized down significantly, a gap is created / the content div starts too low.  Shrink the page, the images shrink, and the content is set down on the page far below the header images (on a smaller screen this is significant).

http://screencast.com/t/aKohSKkr

https://jsfiddle.net/b2tngLym/6/

Comment: That's awesome!  Can you explain the difference?

Comment: I see you added left and top of 0 to the logo image, and position relative to the first inner div, but I'd like to understand conceptually how that fixed it.

Comment: He removed the absolute positioning from the large background image and used its height to fix the height of the .innerdiv1. Alternativly, you could use an padding-bottom at the .innerdiv1 to the ratio of the image (124/500 = 24.8%) and use that as a source of height, but it is more correct to justify the content height by the image height.